# Получить список файлов с подпапками в макос swift

Tags: swift, macos

Получить список файлов с подпапками в макос swift

Везде в инете код который предлагает это сделать из documentDirectory , но мне нужно указать произвольную папку из OpenPanel и далее сгенерировать листинг всего что там есть, то есть эта папка может быть и на сьемном диске и на флеш, код показанный ниже не работает так,  он предлагает отплясывать от папки Документов текущего пользователя. Не знаю в какую сторону рыть или я что то совсем не понимаю,,,, вот код предлагаемый везде но не работающий с произвольными папками

```
func contentsOf(folder: URL) -> [String] {
    var fList = [String]()
    let documentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
    let myFilesPath = documentDirectoryPath
    let files = FileManager.default.enumerator(atPath: myFilesPath)
    while let file = files?.nextObject() {
        print("\(myFilesPath)/\(file)")
        fList.append("\(myFilesPath)/\(file)")
    }
    return fList
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена:

```
    func contentsOf(folder: URL) -> [String] {
    var fList = [String]()
    let files = FileManager.default.enumerator(atPath: folder.path)

    while let file = files?.nextObject() {
        print("\(folder)\(file)")
        fList.append("\(folder)\(file)")
    }
    return fList
}
```